# Java calculate confidence interval

Tags: java, confidence-interval

I'm looking for some method that takes or does not take parameters for calculate confidence interval.
I don't want the apache methods,
just a simple method or som type of code that does this.

Comment: what do mean by confidence interval

Comment: show your work - what are you trying to do, what did you try, what specifically do you not understand?

Comment: Don't be discouraged by vote down, take your time and write a proper description with example for the problem that you are facing

Comment: @RiteshK -  http://evolution.gs.washington.edu/gs560/2011/lecture3.pdf

Answer (score -2, accepted):

here is you go this is the code calculate Confidence Interval

```
/**
 *
 * @author alaaabuzaghleh
 */
public class TestCI {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int maximumNumber = 100000;
        int num = 0;
        double[] data = new double[maximumNumber];

        // first pass: read in data, compute sample mean
        double dataSum = 0.0;
        while (num<maximumNumber) {
            data[num] = num*10;
            dataSum  += data[num];
            num++;
        }
        double ave = dataSum / num;


        double variance1 = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            variance1 += (data[i] - ave) * (data[i] - ave);
        }
        double variance = variance1 / (num - 1);
        double standardDaviation= Math.sqrt(variance);
        double lower = ave - 1.96 * standardDaviation;
        double higher = ave + 1.96 * standardDaviation;

        // print results
        System.out.println("average          = " + ave);
        System.out.println("sample variance  = " + variance);
        System.out.println("sample standard daviation    = " + standardDaviation);
        System.out.println("approximate confidence interval");
        System.out.println("[ " + lower + ", " + higher + " ]");
}
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this calculation is wrong - it should be `ave + 1.96 * standardDeviation / Math.sqrt(num - 1)` resp `ave - 1.96 * standardDeviation / Math.sqrt(num - 1)`. Also, it is confusing that num seems to be one more than the sample size in the above code... and typos don't help the reader's understanding either!

Answer (score 4):

My knowledge is restricted, it basically boils down to completing an online task against an expected set of answers (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/stat-warmup).

However, as far as I read up, there are mistakes in the given answer, and I'd like to correct these. 
My source is pretty much wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Basic_Steps

```
/**
 *
 * @return int[]{lower, upper}, i.e. int array with Lower and Upper Boundary of the 95% Confidence Interval for the given numbers
 */
private static double[] calculateLowerUpperConfidenceBoundary95Percent(int[] givenNumbers) {

    // calculate the mean value (= average)
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int num : givenNumbers) {
        sum += num;
    }
    double mean = sum / givenNumbers.length;

    // calculate standard deviation
    double squaredDifferenceSum = 0.0;
    for (int num : givenNumbers) {
        squaredDifferenceSum += (num - mean) * (num - mean);
    }
    double variance = squaredDifferenceSum / givenNumbers.length;
    double standardDeviation = Math.sqrt(variance);

    // value for 95% confidence interval, source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Basic_Steps
    double confidenceLevel = 1.96;
    double temp = confidenceLevel * standardDeviation / Math.sqrt(givenNumbers.length);
    return new double[]{mean - temp, mean + temp};
}
```

Comment: this calculation seems of being correct for small samples. However, I've read https://sciencing.com/calculate-confidence-levels-2844.html and it seems that for small samples it could be improved?