# Calculate confidence interval for 1 dimension random data

Tags: confidence-interval

I want to know how to calculate the given confidence interval for 1 dimension (this could simplify the question) random data.

The situation is like this: suppose I have 50 random points of data from 1 to 100 (not normally distributed), and I want to know the min range that we have for  90% of the data points located in that range.

This is quite similar to the confidence interval for normal distribution.

Is there any one can help me on this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question would be more suited to the [mathematics stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/), but since it is here I'm gonna [roll with it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DrARl0dzd-0).

You don't specify in which programming language you want to achieve this, therefore I believe your problems lie elsewhere, in the theoretical realm of the subject. Thus the best I can do is to point you to good topics about your question.

After doing some research, this is what I found:

- Wikipedia's page on Confidence Intervals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval
- Khan Academy Confidence interval explained (I highly recomend it !): https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability/statistics-inferential/confidence-intervals/v/confidence-interval-1
- Stat Treck summary on Confidence intervals: http://stattrek.com/estimation/confidence-interval.aspx

With this in mind, I also took the liberty of checkign *other StackOverflow* questions. And I found something that I believe is exactly what you need:

- [Java calculate confidence interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30340551/java-calculate-confidence-interval)

Hope it helps!